# Can't access BIOS - how do I alter the UEFI settings?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, uefi, win10-fast-startup

```
Update & Security > Recovery > Restart > Troubleshoot
```

I can't access the `UEFI Firmware settings` using the path above on my updated Windoes 10 PC. The *Troubleshooting* options are all there `System Restore`, `System Image Recovery`, etc. EXCEPT the one I need `UEFI Firmware settings`. It's simply missing. It was there a few months ago.

How do I alter the UEFI settings now to disable fast boot? I can't get in my Lenovo BIOS no matter how much I hammer on the `Esc`, `F2`, `Enter`, `Delete`, `etc.` keys.

Comment: Just boot while pressing the BIOS/UEFI key, normally F2.

Comment: Sometimes, holding down the key works. You could also physically remove the boot drive.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to access Windows 10 boot options.

All you need to do is hold down the Shift key on your keyboard and restart the PC.
Open up the Start menu and click on “Power” button to open power options.
Now press and hold the Shift key and click on “Restart”.
Windows will automatically start in advanced boot options after a short delay.

Comment: He wrote in the first sentence that he cannot access the settings this way.